# working with parent and child relationship

Tags: mapping, parent, relationship

i have table which has 4 columns

> catId int identity(1,1), ParentId int,
>   LiveCatId, LiveParentCatId int

here the livecatid and liveparentcatid are the fields from the live database and i want to migrate it to the development database table...

now i have catId as it is identity field, LiveCatid, and LiveParentCatId from live database.
i want to map the parent child relationship as it is in the live... that means as the Live Database's LiveCatId and LiveParentCatId are mapped, want to do same between Catid and ParentCatId

Please help me for the logic to achive the task... i am not getting how to get started...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What database? This is not important to the methodology, which is "create change scripts", but the method of doing it depends on the database. SQL Server allows you to make changes to a database and script them out so you can apply these "change scripts" to a database in test environments or even production.

A good read is Refactoring Databases. It gives some methodologies around this subject.